# How to convert tkinter get function String to int in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.7

```
 name=Entry()
x=name.get()
```

I have `print(int(x))` But it gives the following error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Coding/Python/first-hit/Mangal's CAFE.py", line 228, in <module>
    print(int(x))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: You're doing it correctly. The error is telling you that `name.get()` is returning an empty string. You can't convert an empty string to an integer.

Comment: If your code example is literally your real code, the problem is that you're calling `get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget. The user won't have time to type anything in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your entry is empty, so maybe that's why calling `int()` gives you that Error. 
I would try to valid first the entry input before casting to `int()` (for example passing *0* if the entry is empty).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said the code is converting "" to an int and therefore fails.  I often use something like the function below.  It can always return an int, whatever the string is.  Or can return something else if the except block executes.

```
def to_int(string, fail = 0):
    try: 
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return fail
```

Usage:

```
v = to_int(entry.get(), fail = None)
if v is None:
    run_notint()
else:
    run_is_int()
```

I find simply returning zero is enough in many situations, in which case the if: else: isn't required.

```
v = to_int(entry.get())
... code to process the integer.
```